# Does anyone know of a way to mock a web service while specifying latency and throughput?

Tags: performance, http, testing, microservices

In order to to experiment with error handling and back-off strategies in a typical "micro-services" architecture, I would like to have a simple "mock" web service that

- has configurable latency and throughput, changeable at runtime
- can handle some thousands of requests per second on cheap hardware

Does anyone know of such a thing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**For the latency part**, [Moco](https://github.com/dreamhead/moco) maybe is what you are looking for.

The following is from [API](https://github.com/dreamhead/moco/blob/master/moco-doc/apis.md#latency)

> Latency
>
> @Since 0.7
>
> Sometimes, we need a latency to simulate slow server side operation.
>
> @Since 0.10.1
>
> It's easy to setup latency with time unit.
>
> Java API

```
server.response(latency(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```

> JSON

```
{  
    "request" : {
        "text" : "foo"
    },
    "response" : {
        "latency": {
            "duration": 1,
            "unit": "second"
        }
    }
 }
```

**For the "thousands of requests per second on cheap hardware" part**, why do you need this feature? Do you just want to simulate a timeout or something else?

Comment: Thanks! I also found that http://wiremock.org/ has support for setting latency.

For the throughput part, yes, I want to be able to simulate timeouts of different types such as connection closed, 503 Service Unavailable, 429 Too Many Requests.

E.g. a web service with a 10ms latency, but with a throughput of 2000 requests/s "suddenly" (due to a node disappearing behind a load balancer for instance), now still has 10ms latency, but a throughput of only a 1000 requests/s. How will the client handle the situation? These are the things I would like to experiment with.